# How to fill cross domain textbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have searched quite long for a solution but did not find anything, that resolves my problem.

I am trying to send some text from my input type="text" on my own domain to a cross domain input type="text".

I have read something for jsonp and ajax can handle this, but until now i have found only examples to read the cross domain into my own domain.

And i want to fill the cross domain textbox with some text value i type in my own domain.

Any example that can handle this is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a web service in your remote server to handle data that you will send from your textbox. Once data properly received to your server, you can store it in your database or file for example.
After that when user send a request to get a html file from the server (that you called cross domain), your php code will have the necessary data to pull it into a cross domain input type="text"
if you want ton establish realtime communication between peers, it is a better idea if you implement a solution based on node js server